# "As follows": Is "follow" here a verb or something else?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I failed to understand the grammatical structure in this pattern.

> The result is shown **as follows**:
>
> [Result]

Is *follow* here a verb or something else? I don't know whether *as do(es)* is grammatically valid or not.

Comment: Technically speaking, **follows** is a verb there because it definitely feels like one, but I would recommend thinking of the entire thing as a set expression rather than two separate words, *as* and *follows*: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as-follows

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+follows) **as follows** is an idiom which is why you shouldn't bother about its grammar. Yet, most importantly, you must bear in mind that this idiom should always be used in its [singular form](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/02/as-follows.html) :

> The reason for its fixed form is that it was originally an impersonal construction = **as it follows**.
>
> Also, Garner’s Modern American Usage (3rd ed.) has this to say:
>
> **As follows** is always the correct form, even for an enumeration of many things. The expression is elliptical for as it follows—not as they follow.